# Why does Rails appear to be acting non-deterministic (on production only) after an update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that I recently added some minor functionality to. The changes are working great on my test server, but when I put them on my production server, I've been getting odd, apparently non-deterministic behavior: the code does different things with the same inputs.

The change I made involved making some HTML data tables on my application sortable server-side by various columns. If I pass in a `:sort_category` and `:sort_direction` parameter in the URL, it'll sort by a certain column in a certain direction, which I do in the controller by sorting the 2D array that the view loops through to generate the table.

In order to allow the user to sort, I had to write a helper method to create the sort link in the header of each table column. This method needed to look at what column the page was sorted by, and if the page was not sorted by this column, then the header text should link to the view sorted by that column in a specified default direction. If the page **was** sorted by this column already, then the link should link to the view sorted by the same column but in the opposite direction, and the link text itself should contain an up or down triangle symbol depending on whether the current sort was ascending or descending. So my helper method ended up looking like this:

```
  def sort_link(title_string, sort_symbol, sort_string, default_dir, page_anchor)
    # This method generates a link to sort a table column.
    # title_string: String for the text the column header should display.
    # sort_symbol: Symbol for the name of the column, so the method can compare it to the sort category to see if the table is already sorted by this column.
    # sort_string: The String that needs to be passed to the link parameters in order to sort by this column.
    # default_dir: The direction this column should be sorted by by default, :asc or :desc
    # page_anchor: The HTML anchor name where this table is located. If the table is not below an anchor, use nil.

    if @sort_cat == sort_symbol
      if @sort_dir == :asc
        category_sort_symbol = "<span class=\"sort_symbol\">&#x25B2;</span>" # Up Triangle
      elsif @sort_dir == :desc
        category_sort_symbol = "<span class=\"sort_symbol\">&#x25BC;</span>" # Down Triangle
      end
    else
      category_sort_symbol = ""
    end

    case default_dir
    when :asc
      sort_dir_string = ['desc','asc']
    else
      sort_dir_string = ['asc','desc']
    end
    link_to([title_string,category_sort_symbol].join(" ").html_safe, url_for(:sort_category => sort_string, :sort_direction => ((@sort_cat == sort_symbol && @sort_dir == default_dir) ? sort_dir_string[0] : sort_dir_string[1]), :anchor => page_anchor), :class => "sort")
  end
```

`@sort_cat` and `@sort_dir` are already defined by the controller based on the `params[]` with some logic to determine which column/direction to sort by by default if no sort parameters are passed to the view.

Then, in the `th` of my cell, I'd call `sort_link`:

```
<tr>
  <th class="airport_country"><%= sort_link("Country", :country, "country", :asc, "airports_list") %></th>
  <th class="airport_city"><%= sort_link("City", :city, "city", :asc, "airports_list") %></th>
  <th class="airport_iata_code"><%= sort_link("Code", :code, "code", :asc, "airports_list") %></th>
  <th class="airport_visits"><%= sort_link("Visits", :visits, "visits", :desc, "airports_list") %></th> 
</tr>
```

So this isn't the prettiest function (I probably could find a way to merge `sort_symbol` and `sort_string` into a single parameter), but it worked exactly as I wanted it to... on my test server.

I uploaded the application to my production server (via FTP), ran `touch tmp/restart.txt`, and my application appeared to be working. I started browsing around all my views with sortable tables, and they worked as they did on the production server... for about 15 minutes.

I started getting views crashing (that had worked just fine a few minutes prior), and I'd made no changes to the code. The application is driven by a database, but I'm the only person with the ability to write to that database, so that shouldn't have changed either. Then, a few minutes later, the views that were crashing began working again. This kept happening; sometimes views would work and sometimes they'd crash, with no changes to the code or database.

I checked my production.log and found that I was getting crashes within the `sort_link` method, and the problem seemed to be that some method parameters being passed into it were either nil or in a format it wasn't expecting. So it almost felt like my server was somehow rolling back the updates I'd made to the controller, and therefore some variables the helper method was expecting weren't present or correct. I contacted my server administrator to check on if anything could be rolling back files, but the answer came back negative.

Incidentally, only the recent changes seem to be affected - none of the code that that was untouched by this update has been behaving oddly.

So I have an application which appears to sometimes set variables and sometimes not, with no changes to the code or data sources.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of banging my head against this one, I discovered the problem; apparently, when I did the original FTP upload of my /app folder to the production server to push the updates I'd made, I'd accidentally uploaded a second copy of the /app folder inside of /app.  Thus, I had two copies of all my application files: one in /app and one in /app/app. The application must have been unsure of which one to use, and since one copy contained my changes and one didn't, it would sometimes work and sometimes not.

Deleting the extra /app/app folder from my server fixed all of the problems I've been having.